# Salesforce: I just hit my server processing time limit

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

I'm a relatively new developer who uses the Force.com IDE on eclipse.

What are some things I could do to avoid this happening in the future? I heard that using Eclipse might not be the efficient way of doing things in general... but I'm very used to it.

Any hints/advice/guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What, exactly, is your question? I use various versions of Eclipse all day (most every day) and don't have any issues at all. It's absolutely the environment of choice for Apex/Visualforce development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolved itself when I migrated to the stand-alone Force.com IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Was it a VF page that timed out? You need to figure out what's taking so long. Do you have an infinite loop, or inefficient loops that are chewing up thousands of statements executed?

Set up a log under Setup > Monitoring > Debug Logs and then run your script again. Check out the profiling and governor limit information at the bottom. It should give you an idea of where time is being spent.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about callout then you can set higher timeout.
In Eclipse can be another type of timeout - during saving files. If you mean this then you should save file(s) one more time.
I'm working with SF for half a year and I have been using Eclipse for developing stuff. I can say that there are no problems with using it.